# how to generate and save the HTML file locally in python 3.x using the sample html template in flask?

Tags: python, html, shell, python-3.x, flask

I am new to python, I want to generate a HTML file from the data that I am getting by running the python script. So I want to embed that data into HTML template and save it as locally. Here my use case is I have to send HTML file as attachment in mail.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that in python 3 flask?

Comment: Have you tried using a template renderer (e.g. Jinja) directly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I have tried render_template from jinja and flask but not getting the exact way how to save the HTML file locally.

Comment: Once you have the text, just save it to a file in the normal way.